# Creating object from another list for a specific ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a following list after joining 2 tables

```
Id   Name  IsActive FeeName Amount
1    Test       1    Fee1    100
1    Test       1    Fee2    200
1    Test       1    Fee3    300
```

I have a class called products

```
 public class Products
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public List<ProductFee> ProductFunding { get; set; }

}
```

Product fee class has FeeName and amount properties,

I need to create a object of above class something like
    1,test,1,List of ProductFee

Comment: If you need it you should create it. What issue you are facing in it?

Comment: I need to create the object from the above list..so that there is a list with ID 1 having a list of Fee's associated with it. As you see there are 3 fee records with ID 1

Comment: @TechRon i got your point , but you just reference that id in your second object with out a foreign key so that at the time of quering you can get your desired data. if you go with the foreign key , you may not achieve your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var products = results.GroupBy(r => new { r.Id, r.Name, r.IsActive }).Select(g => new Products(){ Id = g.Key.Id, ProductName = g.Key.Name, IsActive = g.Key.IsActive, ProductFunding = g.Select(p => new ProductFee(){ FeeName = p.FeeName, Amount = p.Amount }).ToList() });
```